# NoMemoryError with OJ gem while trying to accelerate JSON conversion in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

We installed the [OJ gem](https://github.com/ohler55/oj) to accelerate JSON conversion in Rails 3.2.12, but we see a `NoMemoryError (failed to allocate memory)` error when attempting to use the code.

Here's where we use the gem in our code:

```
# Render results
render :json => { :version => version, :foo => Oj.dump(foo), :bar => Oj.dump(bar) }
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: How much data are you attempting to serialize, and how much RAM do you have?

Comment: 5 GB of RAM and serializing about 1 MB of data

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem; I've used Oj to serialize much more than that. Are you positive that you don't have a circular reference in your data? Consider opening a bug on the Oj project. :)

Comment: sometimes the data to serialize is up to 2 MB but not much more. previously, we used rails .to_json on the foo and bar objects without issue. does that prove we don't have a circular reference? did you do anything else besides adding "require oj"? maybe we're doing something wrong with oj?

Comment: Try dumping an object without OJ, then load and re-dump it with OJ; that'll at least verify whether it's OJ choking on the actual data, or if it's a problem with your pre-serialization data.

Comment: what do you mean dumping without OJ? you mean using the default "to_json" method? we already can convert objects to JSON using "to_json". also, about how long does it take to serialize your large objects? new relic is showing that serializing large objects (~2 MB) takes around 3-4 sec sometimes. this seems awfully slow. is this consistent with your experience?

Comment: btw, @ChrisHeald, after looking at your website, it seems like you're a mongo expert. we're thinking about switching to mongoid from mongomapper because our rails app runs waaaay slower than it should, and we suspect that mongomapper may be one cause. any thoughts on this?